# cv.imread() pixel-level errors between py2 and py3

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm debugging an image-related program in py2 and py3 environments. The strange point is, the performance in py3 env is always belower than that in py2 env. So I traced back to the very beginning,and I found that after the first `cv.imread()`, there exists pixel-level errors. The two pixels at the same location but in different envs having an difference of `1.` .What may be the reason leading to this problem?

Comment: I suppose this has to do with floating point representation. This shouldn't affect performance though. Give extra info: how big is the difference, which method you use etc

Answer (score -1):

Compare versions of all involved libraries. Is the file compressed or something like jpg?

I feel like this will not happen with something like PNG, but maybe with something like JPG that is compressed and needs to be uncompressed.

It is quite possible that your openCV has different version and uses different way to open JPG.

By opening PNG, I cannot believe this could happen because PNG is raw array

Comment: PNG is also a compressed format, but it's loss-less, as opposed to the lossy JPEG.

Comment: @DanMašek Well my point was that JPG needs to be encoded and maybe different version of cv2 will use different encoding and therefore the resulting image will be different

Comment: Yes it is a `.jpeg` file. I'll try to find more clues.